# Knowing what user searched on Google to come on my website

Tags: search, seo, keyword

I would like to know what user searched on google to come to my website, my website is build in php, I dump **$_SERVER** variable but I didn't find anything related to search keywords. 
is  it possible to find what user searched to come to my website? if yes how can I?

Answer (score 1):

With SSL searches from Google, you can no longer get the keywords from their search:

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/google-hides-search-referral-data-with-new-ssl-implementation-emergency-whiteboard-friday

That may be why you're not getting those variables in the SERVER variable.

Comment: SSL or without it, I am simply not getting value in HTTP_REFERER

Answer (score 0):

Only way how to check this is to look in HTTP header for Referer field where you might find URL where user came from. Then you have to parse it on your own if it's a google URL.

Comment: in I am getting this value for referrer :  [HTTP_REFERER] => https://www.google.co.in/

Answer (score 0):

Just take the case of Google, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] return you url of the Google search result, like

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&aq=f&oq=stackoverflow&aqs=chrome.0.57j61j60j58j60l2.4259&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8
```

now you can extract your search query from it using following code segment

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$start = strpos($url, "search?q=");
$keyword = substr($url, $start + 9, strpos($url, "&", $start));
```

$keywork will return you the exact string that the user enter for search. It only works for Google, like that you can built function for other search engine.

But you can use any analytics tools like Google analytics or any other as a alternative.

Comment: but in my case value is  [HTTP_REFERER] => www.google.co.in    only

Comment: oh yes, Google just ended to providing full url into HTTP_SERVER becuase of user preference and security, so sadly there is no way to find it manually using php, but you can use Google analytics for it, but then also if user don't want to allow you to see search term, you can not see them because of encryption